# Help me setup a good mining rig on my high end gaming computer

Tags: mining, mining-hardware

I will put down my computer setup here:

- CPU: Intel core i7 7820X Skylake-X.3.60GHz
- MB: MSI X299 SLI PLUS Skylake-X. (MS.7A93)
- Memory: DDR 4. 32GB, 2400MHz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 8GB GDDR5X
- Clocks: Core 139MHz, Memory 405MHz.
- Internet speed: FIBER net. 100MB/S up and down. 4MS latency.

How can I setup that machine as a mining rig in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 5):

Its really not that hard.

Create your wallet (GUI works well)

install: 
[XMR-Stak](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak)

XMR-Stak seems to work well (one unified version for CPU & GPUS:AMD/NVidia).  I did build it for linux, but there are prebuilt versions.
Then fire it up, answer questions (no to nicehash, and probably no to multiple pools) and point to to a pool (monerohash.com, xmrsupport.com, etc. Avoid minergate at ALL costs)
You can tweak settings in the .config file. (if Windows use notepad, NOT wordpad, word to edit the config.  ultra basic text file, no formatting codes)  Most pool sites have guides.
Basically you point it at an address and port.  Some want a user:password, typically just an email address.

While your mining your XRM, run monerod to fully sync your node.  It will be sync'd before you get a payout from a pool.  (wallet won't show balance until fully sync'd)

But to give you some insight:  I'm running a I7 (some version) 32GB and 3 GTX 1070's (8GB) and getting about .08 XMR a day.
(But I built the rig for password hashes not mining)